# ReactRouter not working with placeholder routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router

Good afternoon I am having some trouble with ReactRouter and how it is handling routes. I am watching the Wes Bos web series on React for Beginners and after following along with the video I one of my two routes is not rendering and I am getting a 404 error in the console.

Here is the code I am working with, just take it on faith that the other components not mentioned work, this is a routing issue anyway.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;

var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory');    

var App = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
          return(
            <div className="catch-of-the-day">
              <div className="menu">
                  <Header tagline="Fresh Seafood Market" num="5000" />
              </div>
              <Order />
              <Inventory />
            </div>
            )
        }
    })
    var StorePicker = React.createClass({
      render: function(){
        return(
          <form className="store-selector">
            {/* Comment goes in here*/}
            <h2>Please enter A Store</h2>
            <input type="text" ref="storeID" required />
            <input type="submit"/>
          </form>
          )
      }
    });
    var routes = (
        <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
          <Route path="/" component={StorePicker}/>
          <Route path="/store/:storeId" component={App}/>
        </Router>
      )
    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById("main"));
```

So this is what happens: my home route is `localhost:3000` and the route `localhost:3000/store/[whatever I type here]` does not work my component does not render and I get a 404 error reading: `http://localhost:3000/store/build/main.js 404 (Not Found)`. When I look into my `build/main.js` file 1) it takes a while to load and 2) the only mention of my route is on line 25366 so looking there for answers was not helpful.

Interestingly I do not get this error when changing the route to look like this:
`<Route path="/store" component={App}/>` but this is incorrect and I feel like the rest of the videos will rely on whatever is typed into the placeholder. I want to solve the problem before it gets worse. I have rewatched the video a few times already with no success. Does anyone have any ideas I have not been working with React long and I'm sure I've missed something.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because your route config is incorrect.

`<Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={StorePicker} >
        <Route path="store/:storeId" component={App} />
      <Route />
    </Router>`

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md

Comment: Interesting. See this history prop(?) on the `Router` component breaks my app. I implemented your solution and it worked until I added the history prop. Without it I have weird URL strings that look like this: `http://localhost:3000/#/store/hello?_k=29bdba` it doesn't look clean but it works, yet when I include that variable I get the 404 error whether or not `<Route path="store/:storeId" component={App} />` is nested in the home route or not. I edited my question to show the variables and dependencies I am including in this file.

Comment: Was hoping you will visit the link to the docs I added. :) You will need to adapt the history to suit your needs. What my solution solves is your problem listed above. More in histories:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md

PS: Also, the url params can be cleaned up with history config.

Comment: Visited the link but I didn't really understand what I was looking at. Interestingly the only time the first link you mentioned in your answer only has the word "history" once on the page. Looking at the second link is much more cryptic. This is my first day using ReactRouter and I really don't know what I'm doing. If you look at my edited post you'll see this: `var createBrowserHistory = require('history/lib/createBrowserHistory')` and it works for the routes `/` and even `/store` but not `/store/:storeId`

Comment: Then I really suggest you do this first: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial

The history param helps your browser navigate through your app's routes as defined. You can leave that out, and your routes will work but you will have an "ugly" url. 

Regarding `/store/:storeId` - as you yourself noted, `/store/hello` works, because your route is testing for routeParams `:storeId`.